# Java-skipping lines containing Strings/booleans when transferring doubles from a file to an array

Tags: java, arrays, io

I am working on a project for school and am having trouble with one part of it. I have a text file in Notepad which contains data concerning each team in the NHL:

```
Washington Capitals
3.02
2.33
85.2
30.6
28.4
True
Dallas Stars
3.23
2.78
82.3
32.0
28.9
True
...
```

I am trying to place all of the doubles in an array, but I can't seem to figure out how to skip all of the lines that contain Strings or booleans.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
    double data[][] = new double[30][6];
    int indexRow = 0, indexCol = 0, tracker = 0;

    File file = new File(fileName);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

    while(input.hasNext())
    {
        if(tracker == 0 || tracker == 6)
        {
            //skip line
            if(tracker == 6)
                tracker = 0;
        }
        data[indexRow][indexCol] = input.nextDouble();

        if(indexCol < 6) indexCol++;
        if(indexRow < 30 && indexCol % 6 == 0)
        {
            indexRow++;
            indexCol = 0;
        }
        tracker++;
    }
```

Is there anyway to skip just lines containing Strings and booleans? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot skip a line because you need to read it first to see if it is a line you want or a line to throw away.  With the format you give, just read the first character of the line and throw away the rest of the line if the first character is a letter.  If the first character is a digit then keep the line.

Comment: This is problematic if the first character is a digit, but the remainder of the line contains non-numeric data.

Comment: @Coop That won't be an issue. The format stays the same throughout as is shown above.

Comment: @JohnEakin ...perhaps.  But team names can begin with a number.  i.e 49ers, 76ers, etc.  The ellipses indicate this is not a complete list.

Comment: @Coop I appreciate the comment. Fortunately, none of the teams in the NHL do begin with a digit and end with words.

Comment: @JohnEakin That's true.  I guess since he is a student, I just see more value in a solution that teaches him how to validate data without making assumptions about the data set.

Comment: I usually prefer to write a simple parser to check data.  YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

You could try it like this...

```
try {
    double d = Double.valueOf(currentLine);
    // is double
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    // isn't
}
```

Comment: That will be slow.  Exceptions generally run slowly as they often signal the end of the program.  Hence the routines do a lot of internal error logging and such, which slows things down.  Sometimes there is no alternative, but in this case there is.

Comment: @rossum, yes exceptions are slow, and you should never use them in real situations like this, but seeing this is a school project, it won't hurt as much and its  cleaner than making a separate method to check if current input is a double floating-point.

Comment: It doesn't need a method.  Just check if `toUpperCase` equals `toLowerCase`.  If they are the same then there are no letters in the line.

Comment: @rossum True but what if the line contains symbols :P

Answer (score 0):

Since an answer was already accepted I wasn't going to offer a solution but the more I thought about it, the more I felt compelled to do so.  The issue I see with the accepted answer is that it makes assumptions about the input data, leaving the door open for runtime exceptions down the road.  The whole point of OOP is to create robust, reusable code, and to offer such a limited scope solution to a someone who is just learning instills bad practices IMO.

One solution that comes to my mind is using regex to check if the string is numeric:

```
public static boolean isNumeric (String s)
{
    return s.matches("[+-]?\\d*\\.?\\d*");
}
```

(Note:  Depending on the range of your numeric values, you may need to modify the regex pattern to allow commas)

As a check to ensure everything is working properly:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String[] nhlData = { "Washington Capitals",
                            "3.02",
                            "2.33",
                            "85.2",
                            "30.6",
                            "28.4",
                            "True",
                            "Dallas Stars",
                            "3.23",
                            "2.78",
                            "82.3",
                            "32.0",
                            "28.9",
                            "True",
                            "0",
                            "-5.",
                            "+100"};

    for (String s : nhlData) {
        System.out.print(s);
        if (isNumeric(s)) {
            System.out.println(" is numeric");
        } else {
            System.out.println(" is not numeric");
    }


    }
}
```

Another solution would be to take leverage the power of a third-party library like [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) which has static methods that include this functionality:  See `StringUtils.IsNumeric()`

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll make sure to take a look at Apache Commons.